# Getting "Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread" while creating spring batch beans

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my Spring batch configuration, I'm trying to setup a partitioned step, which accesses values from JobParameters as follows :

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("partitionJob")
public Job partitionJob() throws Exception {

    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("partitionJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(partitionStep(null))
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope //I'm getting exception here - > Error creating bean 
public Step partitionStep(
        @Value("#{jobParameters[gridSize]}") String gridSize)
        throws Exception {

    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("partitionStep")
            .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner())
            .gridSize(
                    StringUtils.isEmpty(gridSize) ? 10 : Integer
                            .parseInt(gridSize))
            .step(slaveStep(50000))
            .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor()).build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Step slaveStep(int chunkSize) throws Exception {

    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("slaveStep")
            .<Person,Person> chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader()),
            .writer(csvFileWriterParts())
            .listener(stepExecutionListener()).build();
}
```

I have added @EnableBatchProcessing annotation to my SpringBoot application.

Since I wanted to access JobParameters while constructing a step, I used @StepScope. I have an example that works fine, without @StepScope annotation, but in that case I'm not accessing any JobParameters or anything from context.

But If I use StepScope annotation on partitionStep, I'm getting

> Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.partitionStep': Scope
>   'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a
>   scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a
>   singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   context holder available for step scope

but If I change it to JobScope, then it is failing at slaveStep() with same error message.

What is the correct scope to be used in such cases and how to resolve this issue I'm getting ?

What is the better way of accessing JobParameters while configuring spring beans ?

Exception stack is as below

> 2018-05-25 21:07:32,075 ERROR [main]
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob : Encountered fatal
>   error executing job
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.partitionStep': Scope 'step' is
>   not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy
>   for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder
>   available for step scope  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:361)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.getName(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sample.main(ExtractApplication.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder
>   available for step scope  at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:346)
>     ... 23 common frames omitted

If I modify to JobScope, I get exception on slaveStep, which is similar to the above exception.

Comment: It's unlikely the exception is thrown inside this class. Show the full stacktrace dude

Comment: I have updated my original post with exception stack.

Comment: This might help you [Scope step issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457107/spring-batch-scope-issue-while-using-spring-boot)

Comment: Thanks for the link provided. I will try the option

Comment: I'm facing same problem with same use case, could you share the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the option [Spring batch scope issue while using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457107/spring-batch-scope-issue-while-using-spring-boot), posted by Manh. I guess it solved the problem. Unfortunately I no longer have access to the code base, to confirm what I did for the fix.

Comment: I had the same issue and the link you shared above had solved the issue. The spring-batch version I am using is **3.0.7.RELEASE**. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The same error is also reported if a Spring Bean annotated with `@StepScope` is accidentally added to a Job.