# SPRING-BATCH ERROR: No context holder available for step scope when using threadPoolExecutor in spring batch application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am currently trying to read data from .dat file and persist it into database using spring batch. I have used threading method with step scope to improve my performance but it seems that spring is unable to create proxy bean for my method. I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope error. I have referenced many questions and references but none seems to address my issue. Please provide me some useful reference or any hints to my problem. Thanks in advance...

MyConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class MyBatchConfiguration 
{
    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean(name="commonJobCompletionListener")
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener jobCompletionlistener() 
    {
        return new JobCompletionNotificationListener();
    }

    @Bean(name="commonTaskExecutor")
    @Scope(value="step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() 
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean(name="cstarU2NavReader")
    @Scope(value="step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public FlatFileItemReader<CSTARU2NAVInputMapperDTO> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) throws IOException 
    {
        FlatFileItemReader<CSTARU2NAVInputMapperDTO> newBean = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        newBean.setName("fileReader");
        newBean.setResource(new InputStreamResource(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(fileName))));
        newBean.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        newBean.setLinesToSkip(1);
        return newBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="cstarU2NavLineMapper")
    public DefaultLineMapper<CSTARU2NAVInputMapperDTO> lineMapper() 
    {
        DefaultLineMapper<CSTARU2NAVInputMapperDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer());
        CSTARU2NAVReader cstarU2NavReader = new CSTARU2NAVReader();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(cstarU2NavReader);
        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean(name="cstarU2NavTokenizer")
    public DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer() 
    {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
        tokenizer.setNames("field1","field12","field13","field14");
        tokenizer.setIncludedFields(0,2,3,5);
        return tokenizer;
    }

    @Bean(name="cstarU2NavBatchProcessor")
    public ItemProcessor<CSTARU2NAVInputMapperDTO, IntReplNav> processor() 
    {
        return new CSTARU2NAVProcessor();
    }

    @Bean(name="cstarU2NavBatchWriter")
    public ItemWriter<IntReplNav> writer() 
    {
        return new CSTARU2NAVWriter();
    }

    @Bean(name="cstarU2NavStep")
    public Step step1() throws IOException 
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("cstarU2NavStep")
                .<CSTARU2NAVInputMapperDTO, IntReplNav>chunk(10)
                .reader(this.reader(null))
                .processor(this.processor())
                .writer(this.writer())
                .taskExecutor(this.taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name="cstarU2NavFileImportJob")
    public Job importUserJob(@Autowired @Qualifier("cstarU2NavStep") Step step1) 
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("cstarU2NavFileImportJob"+new Date())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(this.jobCompletionlistener())
                .flow(step1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

}
```

JobCompletionNotificationListener.java

```
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport
{

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor; 

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) 
    {
        if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) 
        {
            taskExecutor.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

ErrorLog

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.commonTaskExecutor': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:362) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$621affe0.shutdown(<generated>) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.listener.JobCompletionNotificationListener.afterJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener.java:20) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeJobExecutionListener.afterJob(CompositeJobExecutionListener.java:60) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:354) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.services.impl.CSTARU2NAVFileServiceImpl.process(CSTARU2NAVFileServiceImpl.java:34) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.services.impl.CSTARU2NAVFileServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b9bdc800.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76) ~[javamelody-core-1.74.0.jar:1.74.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.services.impl.CSTARU2NAVFileServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76b5d896.process(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.services.impl.FileProcessServiceImpl.processFile(FileProcessServiceImpl.java:71) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.services.impl.FileProcessServiceImpl.execute(FileProcessServiceImpl.java:56) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.services.impl.FileProcessServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a723fea.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76) ~[javamelody-core-1.74.0.jar:1.74.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.services.impl.FileProcessServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d2008294.execute(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.controllers.BatchController.fileProcess(BatchController.java:36) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.controllers.BatchController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50364d5.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76) ~[javamelody-core-1.74.0.jar:1.74.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at com.capgroup.horizon.pricecapture.controllers.BatchController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2350dc35.fileProcess(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:873) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.NormalStrategy.doFilter(NormalStrategy.java:38) ~[logbook-servlet-1.12.1.jar:?]
    at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:39) ~[logbook-servlet-1.12.1.jar:?]
    at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31) ~[logbook-servlet-1.12.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239) ~[javamelody-core-1.74.0.jar:1.74.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215) ~[javamelody-core-1.74.0.jar:1.74.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    ... 112 more
```

Link for sample project to reproduce the above issue : https://github.com/Anand450623/Spring-Batch

Comment: [Spring batch scope issue while using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616094/725306) this may also be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `@Scope` from `taskExecutor` bean, this should get fixed.

```
@Bean(name="taskExecutor")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() 
{
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but unfortunately it doesn't seems to solve my issue as my application is a mvc application and i'm triggering job every time a rest call is made. If i remove @Scope annotation then then thread will be created and used only for first iteration or job execution and they will be terminated afterwards, next time whenever the call will be made due to singleton scope i'll get terminated threads so no use of those. In short, it will become only a one time code which is as good as using batch at start up but my requirement says it to be a mvc application.

Comment: If you want to review the code to test it on local to get an exact idea of what i'm trying to say please clone the sample code from my git repo : https://github.com/Anand450623/Spring-Batch

Comment: Please share any other suggestions you have that may help me out...
Thanks in advance

Comment: In that case, try using `@JobScope`instead of `@StepScope`.   After making that change am able to invoke run API multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir...
It worked very smoothly and as expected...
I still i wonder what makes JobScope better than StepScope means both seems to intansiate the beans everytime then why stepscope wasn't working....

Answer (score -2):

You need to add `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation on your configuration class or manually declare the `Step` scope in your application context:

```
@Bean
public StepScope stepScope() {
    StepScope stepScope = new StepScope();
    stepScope.setAutoProxy(false);
    return stepScope;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have used both ways but it doesn't make any difference. I have uploaded the sample project to re produce the error in github as well. The Link to repo is: https://github.com/Anand450623/Spring-Batch

If possible please check the project once and suggest me some solution for my problem.