# SPRING-BATCH ERROR: No context holder available for step scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

This is my simple job configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Testjob {
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    @org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope
    public Step step1() {   
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                            .tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                                System.out.println("Hello World !");
                                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                            }).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("step1")
    public Job job1() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                            .start(step1())
                            .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
        public StepScope stepScope() {
            StepScope stepScope = new StepScope();
            stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
            return stepScope;
        }

}
```

As you can see I have configured the `stepScope` bean as instructed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187418/7134737) and and also added the following line to my `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

---

This is the error I am getting. **Where am I going wrong ?**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.step1': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy359.getName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:115) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy360.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:192) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.foo.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

**Please note my project has 2 datasources configured, along with Spring MVC Web:**

**Datasource 1**, for JPA/Hiberate:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
        basePackages = {"com.foo.repositories"})
public class JpaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @DependsOn({"dataSourceProperties"})
    public DataSource hikariDataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
    
    @Bean("entityManagerFactory")
    @DependsOn({"hikariDataSource"})
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder
            entityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("hikariDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.hib.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", env.getProperty(
                "spring.hib.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"));
        
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder.dataSource(dataSource)
                                .persistenceUnit("TestPersistenceUnit")
                                .properties(properties)
                                .packages("com.foo.entities")
                                .build();
    }
```

**DataSource 2**, for Spring Batch JDBC Job Repository:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchFrameworkConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Bean("batch_datasource_properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.batch.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean("batch_datasource")
    @DependsOn({"batch_datasource_properties"})
    public DataSource batchFrameworkDatasource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"batch_datasource"})
    public BatchConfigurer defaultBatchConfigurer(@Qualifier("batch_datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }
    
}
```

I am unable to find the mysterious XML mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616094/7134737).

**What is going wrong ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Year is 2020, SpringXMLConfiguration is called **mysterious XML** :) It is just an alternative way of configuring beans, just define the bean with the same id in your code in `@Configuraiton` file.

Comment: @JAsgarov I did. I defined the `StepScope` bean. In my Job Config. Is that not correct ?

Comment: @JAsgarov i dont understand what you are referring to.

Comment: @JAsgarov What bean id ??

Answer (score 4):

**My mistake.**

`@StepScope` should be declared like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Testjob {
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet helloWorldTasklet() {
        return (stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello World !");
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }
    
    @Bean   
    public Step step1() {   
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                            .tasklet(helloWorldTasklet())
                            .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job1() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                            .start(step1())
                            .build();
    }
    
    
}
```

**Notice that the `helloWorldTasklet` bean is declared as `@StepScope` and not my `@Step`.**

Answer (score 0):

Using Java configuration, you don't need to register yourself the StepScope (this is for XML), add the annotation @EnableBatchProcessing on your configuration. In your case, you don't need to add @StepScope and @DependsOn.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Testjob {

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {   
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                            .tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                                System.out.println("Hello World !");
                                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                            }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job1() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                        .start(step1())
                        .build();
    }    

}
```

Use @JobScope and @StepScope on bean used in your step or job when you need a new instance for each job or step.

Comment: I need StepScope. I would like to know how I can configure that. Yes for this job I don'r need StepScope per se, but I need it for other more complex jobs.

Comment: The question is why doesn't StepScope work here, not that it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, but it was my mistake. Posted the corrected answer.

Comment: Great to hear you solve your issue. Yes, you need to put on beans used inside a step to have the context initiliazed.