# Passing parameters to itemreader through @StepScope or @JobScope

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I´m trying to inject parameters from an outside context to an `ItemReader` using spring batch.

Below I have my code that trigger the job:

```
    Date date = Date.from(advanceSystemDateEvent.getReferenceDate().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());      
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jobParametersBuilder.addLong("uniqueness", System.nanoTime());
    jobParametersBuilder.addDate("date", date);     
    jobLauncher.run(remuneradorJob, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
```

My job:

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class JobsConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job remuneradorJob(Step remuneradorStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("remuneradorJob")
            .start(remuneradorStep)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .build();
    }
}
```

My step:

```
@Configuration
public class StepsConfig {

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public Step remuneradorStep(ItemReader<Entity> remuneradorReader, ItemWriter<Entity> remuneradorWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
            .get("remuneradorStep")
            .<Entity, Entity>chunk(1)
            .reader(remuneradorReader)
            .writer(remuneradorWriter)
            .build();
}
}
```

My itemreader:

```
@Configuration
public class RemuneradorReaderConfig {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;  

@Bean
@StepScope
public JpaPagingItemReader<Entity> remuneradorReader(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map jobParameters) {

    //LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2011,5,16);
    JpaPagingItemReader<Entity> databaseReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
    databaseReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    databaseReader.setQueryString("...");
    databaseReader.setPageSize(1000);
    databaseReader.setParameterValues(Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("limit", localDate));
    return databaseReader;
}
}
```

I got the error:

> Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.remuneradorReader': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope

I tried replacing `@StepScope` for `@JobScope`, but I got the same error.

I saw this issue:

[Spring batch scope issue while using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457107/spring-batch-scope-issue-while-using-spring-boot)

And finally, the application runs.

But now I´m facing another problem, according the code below:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JpaPagingItemReader<Entity> remuneradorReader(@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map jobParameters) {

JpaPagingItemReader<Entity> databaseReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
databaseReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
databaseReader.setQueryString("select o from Object o");
databaseReader.setPageSize(1000);
return databaseReader;
}
```

When I execute this reader, it gives me:

> Deposit{Deposit_ID='null', Legacy_ID ='null', Valor_Depósito='10000', Saldo='10000'}

The `idDeposit` and `idLegacy` comes `null`.

But when I remove `@StepScope` and `@Value("#{jobParameters}") Map jobParameters from ItemReader`, like code below:

```
@Bean
public JpaPagingItemReader<Entity> remuneradorReader() {

JpaPagingItemReader<Entity> databaseReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
databaseReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
databaseReader.setQueryString("select o from Object o");
databaseReader.setPageSize(1000);
return databaseReader;
}
```

The reader gives me the correct response:

> Deposit{Deposit_ID='98', Legacy_ID ='333', Valor_Depósito='10000', Saldo='10000'}

I think it´s missing something else.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch scope issue while using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457107/spring-batch-scope-issue-while-using-spring-boot)

Comment: I saw this issue above, but I still have doubts about the problem. For example, where I put this xml: 

<bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
    <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
</bean>

Another doubt:

I tried this piece of code:

@Bean
public StepScope stepScope() {
    final StepScope stepScope = new StepScope();
    stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
    return stepScope;
}

But the IDE doesn´t allow me instantiate StepScope class, because it´s an abstract class.

Comment: `StepScope` is not an abstract class: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/StepScope.java#L65.

Comment: I made a wrong import. The correct is this one: import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope;

Comment: Yes, with this one, it should work, as mentioned in the duplicate question.

Comment: I edited the question above.

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.